# Cómo puedo mostrar en un SELECT lo que está seleccionado en la base de datos

Tags: php, html

Hice un select de rangos administrativos, en el cuál al elegir uno y darle al botón de enviar funciona. Pero quiero mostrar en el mismo select lo que seleccionó anteriormente al enviar como default, es decir. Si seleccionó antes 'option="1"'(que sería el rango de moderador), al recargar la página muestre esa misma selección que hizo como predeterminada. Perdonen si no me explico muy bien.

```
Rango<br>
// Ya seleccionado, que muestre el <option> elegido anteriormente como default
<select name='rankc'>
<option value='1'>Usuario</option>
<option value='2'>Vip</option>
</select>
<br><br>

    $stmt = $db->prepare("UPDATE users SET username = ?, motto = ?, rank = ?, credits = ?, pixels = ?, points = ?, pais = ?, tarea = ? WHERE username = ?");
                    $stmt->bind_param('sssssssss', $_POST["usernamec"], $_POST["mottoc"], $_POST["rankc"], $_POST["creditsc"], $_POST["pixelsc"], $_POST["pointsc"], $_POST["paisc"], $_POST["tareaType"], $_POST["usernamec"]);
                    $stmt->execute();
```

Gracias de antemano. :)

Answer (score 0):

Puedes crear una variable en el localStorage que almacene el resultado que se seleccionó en dicho select, y luego, al recargar la página, que se imprima en el  del select el valor de la variable que creaste en el localStorage, para hacer todo ésto, te recomendaría emplear Javascript, yo te daré alguna idea pero con jQuery:

```
$(document).ready(function(){

    var valor = localStorage.getItem("opcionEscogida");

    if(valor != null && valor != "undefined"){

    $('select[name="rankc"]').find("option[value="+valor+"]").prop('selected','selected');

    }

})

$("select[name="rankc"]").change(function(){

    var opcion = $(this).val();

    localStorage.setItem("opcionEscogida", opcion);

})
```

Si tienes alguna duda o algún error, me comentas.

Comment: Tendría que editar el código, o hacerlo en javascript. Para probarlo y haber sí funciona.

Comment: Te funcionará, estoy totalmente seguro.